# an eternal verity "which, attending," has planted

Tags: punctuation, relative-clauses, archaic-language

Forth from the age-yellowed pages (of the book) there leapt an eternal verity; which, **attending**, has planted new seeds of wisdom in the soil of my mind. (an internal meditation on the Holy Bible 1890)

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is mispointed; the commas are misleading:

> Forth from the age-yellowed pages there leapt an eternal verity; which attending has planted new seeds of wisdom in the soil of my mind.

*Which attending* is an old-fashioned inversion of *attending which*. And that transitive use of *attending* is also pretty obsolete; today we would say *attending **to***. The sense is

> ... attending to which [=‘that verity’] has planted new seeds of wisdom ...

Comment: @StoneyB I haven't noticed that this sense of *attend* is obsolete (and *attend to* is preferred)! (I think of it the same way as *attending a school or a church*.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. The sense here is "pay close attention to", and in that sense it is rare today.

Comment: @user08742 No; for *attending* to be understood as a participle modifying *I*, *I* would have to be present in the clause. It has to be a gerund.

Comment: Then what about this?Not having that which, having, makes them short.